# usar o no usar llaves dentro de un if o else en c++

Tags: c++, condiciones

Tengo una duda, ¿Afecta en algo que al declarar un if(){} utilice llaves{}?, ya que si no se le declaran aun así funciona igualmente, código de ejemplo sin llaves:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x;
    
    cin>>x;
    
    if(x == 1)
        cout<<"X es uno"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<x;
        cout<<" no es uno"<<endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

la salida al parecer funciona igual que con llaves y estoy confundido.

Comment: No tiene sentido. Cuando ejecutes el código y le pases un 1 deberían imprimirse ambos mensajes. Inténtalo y dinos como te fue

Comment: No es lo mismo. Las llaves generan un ambito de ejecucion completo. No importa la identacion, importan las llaves. En este caso, como el  else no tiene, entonces cuando x sea 1, se van a imprimir tanto el mensaje X es uno, como no es uno. O sea si, son importantes para definir el ambito de ejecucion de un contexto.

Comment: @Mateo compila igual como si fuera un if normal, le di valor 6 y solo muestra lo que esta dentro del else, será que el compilador asume que hay llaves?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la explicación, pues si ha sucedido y creo que estas son pequeñas preguntas que uno como novato se hace y no se dicen

Comment: Antonio, no hay problema con el else, si no modificaste el código, el problema sucede cuando le pasas un 1, entonces recibes en la consola: "X es uno no es uno"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las llaves `{ }` (corchetes son estos: `[ ]`) se usan para delimitar bloques de código.

En general se escriben entre llaves los bloques en los que contienen una o más instrucciones de código. Por ejemplo:

```
if (true) {
    cout << "Hola"; // 1
    cout << "Adiós"; // 2 
}
// 2 líneas, 2 instrucciones
```

Cuando se trata de una sola instrucción puedes evitar usar las llaves como has notado. En el caso de no usarlas, será la instrucción siguiente la que se verá afectada por el condicional o el ciclo. Si, funciona con `if`, `for`, `while` y `do while`. Nunca intenté hacerlo con `switch`, funciones, clases o structs pero es raro que uses alguna estructura de esas solo para que dentro tenga una única instrucción.

Cómo puedes notar y como dijo **gbianchi**, no es lo mismo. C en particular es un lenguaje muy poco permisivo en cuanto a sintaxis, aunque te da la libertad de hacer cosas como pasar un int como condición a un `if` o `while` y funcionará.

**Actualización:**
Nótese que hablo de instrucciones y no de líneas porque no son lo mismo. Puede haber una instrucción que ocupe 2 líneas como ejemplificó ArtEze, así como también 2 instrucciones por línea. Por ejemplo, puede ser común ver algo como:

```
int n;
cout << "Ingrese un número: "; cin >> n;
```

Comment: las llaves no delimitan bloques de código ... delimitan **ámbitos**. Usar ámbitos permite limitar la vida de las variables mientras que un bloque de código no es más que una serie de instrucciones que viajan juntas

Comment: No sé exactamente quién hace a quién. Discutir eso sería como debatir quien fue primero si el huevo o la gallina. Lo que sí sé es que los ámbitos son inherentes a los bloques de código delimitados por llaves.

Comment: mira mi respuesta. No existe una estructura de if con llaves y otra de if sin llaves. Las llaves sirven para lo que sirven y el lenguaje te deja ponerlas justo después de un if. Se ve mejor en los case, si no pones llaves olvídate de declarar variables dentro de un case

Answer (score 2):

Se puede usar solo cuando hay solamente una sentencia.

Lo siguiente se puede simplificar para que quede una sentencia:

```
if(x == 1)
    cout<<"X es uno"<<endl;
else
    cout<<x;
    cout<<" no es uno"<<endl;
```

Se aprovecha que la segunda sentencia también es `cout`:

```
if(x == 1)
    cout<<"X es uno"<<endl;
else
    cout<<x<<" no es uno"<<endl;
```

También se puede separar las sentencias en varias líneas:

```
if(x == 1)
    cout<<"X es uno"<<
      endl;
else
    cout<<x<<
    " no es uno"<<
    endl;
```

Es decir, termina cuando analiza sintácticamente la sentencia... Digo esto porque yo podría decir, *hasta que aparezca el punto y coma*, pero no es suficiente ya que pueden haber caracteres como ese dentro del string.

Answer (score 1):

Si le damos de entrada a tu programa:

```
1
```

El resultado es:

```
X es uno
 no es uno
```

Lo que claramente no es lo que quieres. El no usar los `{}` funciona solo si es
una instruccion. Yo te recomendaria colocarlos siempre.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí estamos mezclando dos conceptos diferentes.

Por un lado tenemos el uso de las llaves. Las llaves permiten crear y delimitar ámbitos. ¿Y esto para qué sirve? Entre otras cosas para limitar la vida de las variables.

Puedes crear ámbitos en prácticamente cualquier parte del código simplemente colocando una pareja de llaves:

```
int a = 1;
{
  int a = 5;
  std::cout << a;
}
std::cout << a;
```

Este programa imprimirá lo siguiente:

```
51
```

Por otro tenemos el funcionamiento del `if`.

Las instrucciones de control `if`, `for`, `while`, solo actuan sobre el bloque de código que sigue a dicha instrucción.

Si no usas llaves, el bloque de código que estará bajo los efectos de la instrucción de control se limitará a la primera instrucción.

Así, el siguiente fragmento:

```
bool a = false;
if (a)
    std::cout << 1; std::cout << 2;
std::cout << 3;
```

Tendrá como salida:

```
23
```

Si lo que pretendemos es que la instrucción afecte a un bloque de código concreto entonces tendremos que usar necesariamente llaves:

```
bool a = false;
if (a)
{
    std::cout << 1;
    std::cout << 2;
}
std::cout << 3;
```

La salida del programa será ahora

```
3
```